# Don't change time when changing picker

Tags: bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

On v4.17.43

So I have a simple picker:

```
$('.datetimepicker .date-range-start').datetimepicker({
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm',
    maxDate:moment().endOf('day')
})
```

and the default date is set in the html to something like '2016-10-31 00:00'

```
<input type="text" class="date-range-start" name="start" value="2016-10-31 00:00" />
```

But whenever you change the day with the picker, the time gets changed to the current time. How can I get it to STAY as 00:00 unless the user actually changes the time with the time part of the picker.

I found one person saying set useCurrent:'day' but thats not changing anything for me.

Comment: Can you add your html code and show how you set default date? Please note that [`useCurrent`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#usecurrent) option takes a boolean value, so to disable you have to use `useCurrent: false` instead of `'day'`

Comment: When I say set default date, I mean I'm instantiating the datepicker on an input with a value of  '2016-10-31 00:00'.
I tried `useCurrent: false` aswell with no change.

I read there was an option to put 'day' 'month' or 'year' in useCurrent that wasn't in the doc, but maybe it was deprecated .

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry that `useCurrent: false` didn't help, anyway I think that adding the html code would help to find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a [`defaultValue`](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#defaultdate) to the picker using data attribute instead of setting `value`, so you will have `data-date-default-date` on your input.

You can find more about `data-*` initialization [here](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Changelog/#400) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35202298/4131048).

Here a working example:

```js
$('.datetimepicker .date-range-start').datetimepicker({
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm',
    maxDate: moment().endOf('day')
})
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.43/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/locale/en-gb.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.43/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class='col-sm-6 datetimepicker'>
    <input type="text" class="form-control date-range-start" name="start" data-date-default-date="2016-10-31 00:00" />
</div>
```

---

Please note that your example will work as you expect if you use version `4.17.37` of the datetimepicker, as shown in the following example. Maybe you can also consider downgrading to a previous version of the datetimepicker.

```js
$('.datetimepicker .date-range-start').datetimepicker({
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm',
    maxDate: moment().endOf('day')
})
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/locale/en-gb.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class='col-sm-6 datetimepicker'>
    <input type="text" class="form-control date-range-start" name="start" value="2016-10-31 00:00" />
</div>
```

Comment: adding the attribute `data-date-default-date` instead of value give me exactly what I want, thanks!
I find this to be pretty unintuitive though :/

Comment: I agree with you, the old version seems to act more _naturally_, anyway I'm happy you solved your issue.